Is there a way to use AD Credentials through LDAP for User Login in a Web Application
I am trying to get the user to login to a web app using their AD creds. But there is an issue where I have to allow "Logon all computers" in "Logon Workstations" in AD. I want the user to only be able to access the web app on their system.
I tried Allowing only the devices that require are involved in the process, the Server with the web app, The server with LDAP configured on the user device. As you might have guessed, it didn't work.
I have not added an authentication process for AD creds in the Web app, could that be the problem?
This issue seems similar to Outlook Web App (OWA). As it would repeatedly show the login form after entering the creds. But would work when logon to all computers was applied.
P.S. The web app is in php and runs internally in the network so, no internet or Firewall is involved.
Can Anyone tell me how to go about this? If you have a solution for it then let me know.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
